# problema al instalar las cabeceras en kali linux

Tags: linux, unix

Hola estaba intentando instalar las cabeceras en mi kali linux para solucionar un error que obtenia en virtual box para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
$ dpkg -i linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
```

Pero cuando actualizo el paquete `linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386_4.6.4-1kali1_i386` a pesar de que incluí ese mismo paquete me da el mismo error:

```
dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
Seleccionando el paquete linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386 previamente no seleccionado.
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 344716 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386 (4.6.4-1kali1) ...
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386:
 linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386 depende de linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686 (= 4.6.4-1kali1); sin embargo:
  El paquete `linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686' no está instalado.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386 (--install):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386
```

Basicamente mi problema es que cuando inicio virtualbox obtengo el siguiente error por lo que estaba intentando actualizar mis cabeceras el error es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las fuentes me las baje de esta pagina:
http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/

Comment: Has probado a ingresar en la terminal y ejecutar `/sbin/vboxconfig`?

Comment: ya funciona no sé esque habia una cabecera que no se podia actualizar la all siempre me pedia la otra pero instale de nuevo virtualbox con el dkms y funciono..

Comment: Genial! En ese caso te recomiendo que agregues la solucion que has realizado para solucionar ese problema, asi si otro tiene el mismo error pueda guiarse :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que hice con un purge borrar la instalacion de mi virtualbox y dkms para hacer la instalación en limpio con las cabeceras nuevas. Primero limpio con purge(solo es necesario en caso de que lo hayais instalado):

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox\* 
sudo apt-get purge dkms\*
```

Despues nos descargamos las cabeceras actualizadas de la siguiente página:

http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/

Una vez descargadas las instalamos:

```
$ dpkg -i linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
```

Hacemos un update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

En mi caso no se me instalaba `linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb`, aún así instale de nuevo dkms y virtualbox y funciono correctamente.
Para instalar dkms hacemos:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Para instalar virtualbox lo descargamos de la pagina oficial(preferiblemente actualizado y si es para kali linux recomendable usar Debian Stretch):

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Y lo instalamos como cualquier otro paquete .deb:

```
dpkg -i el_paquete_actualizado_de_virtualbox.deb
```